# DCOPSERVER not running plus both partitions full on Asus Eee PC 900

Tags: linux, installation, partitioning, repository, eee-pc

I'm new to Linux and have recently purchased an Asus Eee PC 900 running Xandros Linux.

My DCOPserver is not running. I can't find the command line to put it back in service.

The 900 came with both partitions active: `/` which is my main and `/ro` which is the secondary. `/ro` has 0 space left on it. Though it is a duplicate of `/` partition it has 19 X11 files.

I don't have a clue why both would be needed for the same directories, more importantly, I have no idea on how to make `/ro` go away.

My ultimate goal is to get to crunchbag. My major obstacles are (besides the above) I don't know how to install a downloaded file. I save it to my documents and am lost after that.

Note: I have no data on this netbook, so if I have to wipe out the hard drive then that is not a problem.

Comment: I have edited your question and removed all the opinions. They only clutter the question and you're less likely to get answers. Also: don't ask 3 questions in one.

Comment: What are you trying to find out?  As mentioned you should only ask 1 question at a time. Do you want to fix DCOPServer, install crunchbag ([Crunchbang?](http://crunchbang.org/)) or fix the `/ro` directory?

Comment: Apologies to all for multiple questions. How do I fix the DCOPServer? eee pc 900 linux xandros